# Table relation to itself in Rails 4

Tags: database, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, one-to-many

Please check the attached image 
[image: prize relation]

as you can see there is a one to many relation between PrizePartner and AvailablePartner

And here is the logic:
One prize partner can select another partner to be his prize partner (on his behalf)

So available partner will have the prize partner id and the id of other prize partner who has been selected.

Here is an example:

PrizePartner:

- Club 1: Smith street football club
- Club 2: John street football club
- Club 3: Richmond football club

Now AvailablePartner

- Club 1 / Club 2
- Club 1 / Club 3

basically club 1 can't afford to pay prize so it points the prize pool to Club 2 and Club 3 pools.

Now if I do this:
PrizePartner

```
has_many :available_partners
```

AvailablePartner

```
belongs_to :prize_partner, :primary_key => :prize_partner_id
```

**Do you think this is a good solution for this, or is there a way that a table can reference itself in rails?**

Thank you.

**A possible answer**

Something like this could help:

A migration:

```
class AddAvailablePartnerToPrizePartner < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :prize_partners, :available_partner_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Then:

```
class PrizePartner < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :partner, :class_name => 'PrizePartner'
  has_many :nominated_partner, :class_name => 'PrizePartner',:foreign_key => :available_partner_id

end
```

In the console:

```
 s = PrizePartner.find(1)
 s.nominated_partner
```

It does work :) Not sure if this is the best way though but it works and I don't need AvailablePartner table

The above solution will not work as one club can add one club as a partner whereas each club should be able to add more than one club as an available partner.

So back to square one :(

Comment: So you want to do a self-join?

Comment: My solution is not going to work. One club should be able to pick more than one club. My solution is only works if one club pick one other club. So I am back to square one.

Comment: I don't peak Rail-ese, so I can't really offer you a solution there, only in normal SQL. Your description makes it sound like you want a self-join though.

Comment: hmmm, in the self-join, one record can join to only one other record correct? or can one record reference more than one records?

Comment: You have all the options you'd have with any other join. Imagine you copied the table and you were joining the original to the copy; it works the same.

Comment: Are you referring to the self-join or having another table to reference it with like the one I have in the image.